# MediaElement doesn't play files from internal memory of device

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I'm writing a simple app which plays mp3 files with help of MediaElement. My test device has SD card. The problem is that app can play files from SD card but can't do that with the same files from internal memory.

Here are simplified parts of my code:

1. MainPage.xaml

   ```
   <Page
       x:Class="TestApp.MainPage"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
       xmlns:local="using:TestApp"
       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
       mc:Ignorable="d">

       <Page.Resources>
           <DataTemplate x:Key="StorageItemDataTemplate">
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding File.Name}" />
           </DataTemplate>
       </Page.Resources>

       <Grid>
           <ListView
               x:Name="List"
               IsItemClickEnabled="True"
               ItemClick="List_OnItemClick"
               ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StorageItemDataTemplate}" />

           <MediaElement x:Name="Media" />
       </Grid>
   </Page>
   ```
2. MainPage.xaml.cs

   ```
   public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
   {
       public MainPage()
       {
           this.InitializeComponent();
       }

       protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
       {
           IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> items = 
               await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFilesAsync();

           List.ItemsSource = items.Select(item => new ItemViewModel(item));
       }

       private void List_OnItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
       {
           var item = (ItemViewModel) e.ClickedItem;
           Media.Source = new Uri(item.File.Path);
       }
   }
   ```
3. ItemViewModel.cs

   ```
   public class ItemViewModel
   {
       public StorageFile File { get; private set; }

       public ItemViewModel(StorageFile file)
       {
           File = file;
       }
   }
   ```

When the item is clicked in the list, file path is extracted and passed to the MediaElement. Next MediaElement plays the audio.

If the file is in the internal memory then file path will looks like this:
`C:\\Data\\Users\\Public\\Music\\file.mp3`

And if it is on the SD card:
`D:\\Music\\file.mp3`

App's manifest has next checked capabilities:

- `Music library`
- `Removable storage`

Where can be the problem?

**UPD**

After subscribsion to the MediaElement's MediaOnMediaFailed event I've got the next error message:
`MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED : HRESULT - 0x80070005`

`0x80070005` means `Access Denied`.

Comment: Can you try to set source of mediaelement by using *MediaElement.SetSource* method - you will have to open *StorageFile* for this with *OpenAsync*, which will provde *IRandomAccessStream* to pass as source. The reason may be because the capabilities are used by *StorageFile*, which works with file broker, I'm not sure if it will work just by passing Uri.

Comment: Thanks. Now all works. But passing Uri is more preferable way in my app. So do you think this is not possible at all?

Comment: If that's not working then probably it's not possible to do it with Uri.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it will work by passing *Uri* - the *StorageFile* is working with file broker which takes advantage of declared capabilities, thus accessing files outside the app is possible. It should work if you do it like this:

```cs
private async void List_OnItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var item = (ItemViewModel) e.ClickedItem;
    var stream = await item.File.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);        
    Media.SetSource(stream, item.File.ContentType);
}
```